# React JS: How not to get markup in final rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I remove `<div className='wrapper'></div>` around `<main></main>` in final rendering:

```
class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <header>Header Content</header>
        <main>Content goes here</main>
        <footer>Footer Content</footer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Result:

```
<div className='wrapper'>
  <header>Header Content</header>
  <main>Content goes here</main>
  <footer>Footer Content</footer>
</div>
```

Expected result without `<div className='wrapper'></div>`:

```
<header>Header Content</header>
<main>Content goes here</main>
<footer>Footer Content</footer>
```

The problem is render can return only one parent `div` (or other tags) and cannot have siblings.

I know how to do it in vue.js but not sure with react.js

```
<template>
  <header>Header Content</header>
  <main>Content goes here</main>
  <footer>Footer Content</footer>
</template>
```

will result in:

```
<header>Header Content</header>
<main>Content goes here</main>
<footer>Footer Content</footer>
```

Comment: What you would need is a way to return a list/array of elements from `render`. Not possible at the moment. This is the github thread where this feature is discussed: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127

Comment: Why do you want to not have the wrapper div?

Comment: @Aaron, there is a situation where I will endup with same wrapper markup twice. There is way to handle this in vue.js, I wish even react had something like that.

Comment: Why does having the wrapper div twice create a problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you just dn't include it in the `render`:

```
class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <main>Content goes here</main>
    );
  }
}
```

or

```
class Projects extends Component {
  render() {
    return <main>Content goes here</main>;
  }
}
```

---

Re the updated question: You wouldn't make that a component. A component must have a single top-level element. You can't, for instance, return an array of elements.

Comment: The problem is render can return only one parent `div` without siblings. So, I need multiple `div` or other tags, is there a way to do it? Please check the modified question.

Comment: @Syed: That changes things. :-) I'm afraid you can't make it a component, components must have a single top-level element.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what do you mean by in *"final rendering"* , but you can add some condition to check whether to include div or not

```
class Projects extends Component {
  constructor(props) { 
    super(props);    
    this.state = {isIncluded: true};
  }
  render() {
    if (isIncluded) { // it will be included only if `isIncluded` true
      <div className='wrapper'>
        <main>Content goes here</main>
      </div>
    }
    else { // otherwise
      return (      
        <main>Content goes here</main>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is render can return only one parent `div` without siblings. So, I need multiple `div` or other tags, is there a way to do it? Please check the modified question.

Comment: Its not possible render must have single returning element, but why do you want to do so?

Comment: there is a situation where I will endup with same wrapper markup twice. I am missing vue.js, it has this feature  :)

Comment: I think You should create parent view (main view) which have header footer and dynamic content is replaced by component

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this (as far as I know). The problem is that React only accepts 1 element and can only render 1 element. That element can have as many siblings as it wants, this is caused by the way React.createElement() works. Remember that jsx `<div> children </div>` is sugar syntax for the createElement function. Refer to the React [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html) for more details

In your specific case, the way you can easily solve this is by rendering each of the 3 parts separately (this is the way it's supposed to be done for Header, Content and Footer anyway).

So, have a component for head another for content and another for footer and render them individually, that way there's no need to have them all in one component.

This depends heavily on the framework you're using too.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is how React works. It expects a single node to be returned for a component due to the underlying architecture.

However, this issue has been discussed in React community and a fix is now available (in version **16RC**). See the release notes here - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10294.

You can update to this version and change your code to something like this -

```
return [
    <header>Header Content</header>,
    <main>Content goes here</main>,
    <footer>Footer Content</footer>
];
```

Though I haven't tried this myself but you can try this and read more about the discussion regarding this issue here - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2127. Hope this helps.